# Spring java object send and receive

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to send Java object from client to Spring controller. I've tried the following. But not working.

My bean class - I have the same package and class in both client and service

```
public class DataObj implements Serializable {

    private String stringData;
    private byte[] byteData;
    public String getStringData() {
        return stringData;
    }
    public void setStringData(String stringData) {
        this.stringData = stringData;
    }
    public byte[] getByteData() {
        return byteData;
    }
    public void setByteData(byte[] byteData) {
        this.byteData = byteData;
    }
}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/an/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void subscribeUser(@RequestBody DataObj subscription){
    System.out.println("DD");
    bytes = subscription.getByteData();
}
```

My Client - Apache

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/contex/an/data");
httppost.setEntity(new SerializableEntity((Serializable) dataObj , false));
httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

My Client - URLConnection

```
  URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/contex/an/data");
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  ObjectOutputStream  writer = new ObjectOutputStream (conn.getOutputStream());
  writer.writeObject(dataObj );
  writer.flush();
  conn.connect();
  writer.close();
  System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
```

Both the execution is not working. The controller trying to redirect to access denied page. Correct me, if my understanding is wrong, pardon me, if it is duplicate. JSON wrapping won't help me, since the java object having byte array. So please note that.

**UPDATE**
I'm receiving the following log

`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters
INFO: Character decoding failed. Parameter...... [Showing my bean class package and the data in non readable format]`

Comment: access denied? Security? Permission?

Comment: add getters and setters to your object

Comment: No, I added `<intercept-url pattern="/an/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />` so, there shouldn't be security issue.

Comment: @AzatNugusbayev getter setters added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, always Servlets are like King. I used the following to make it work

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest context;
@RequestMapping(value = "/an/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String send() {
    System.out.println("EEE");
    try{
        ObjectInputStream obj =  new ObjectInputStream(context.getInputStream());
        DataObj v = (DataObj )obj.readObject();
        System.out.println(v.getStringData());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return "CAME";
}
```